# Override jQuery UI DatePicker _generate HTML Function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In jQuery UI 1.7, I had successfully overridden the datepicker._generateHTML function running a script in the form:

```
jQuery.datepicker._generateHTML = function(inst) {
  ...revised code...
};
```

When I attempted to upgrade to version 1.8 using the same approach, I encountered a problem. Version 1.8 added a datepicker closure scope variable `dpuuid`, which is referenced in the new version of the '...revised code...'. datepicker._generateHTML now fails with a `dpuuid is not defined' error`.

I'm still new enough to Javascript to not understand all the subtle aspects of the language. So my first question is: 'Can a function which references a closure scope variable be overridden and still access the original closure scope?'

Comment: The default implementation does many things I don't need - I'm basically after a wall calendar functionality. I replace _generateHTML to force a 6 row display, non-selectable dates, and other limitations.

Comment: @claytoncarney: You can always add your comment / solution as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: I attempted to do that, however I received an error stating that new users must wait 8 hours before answering their own questions. Go figure...

Comment: Thought about that, but never found a good plugin tutorial.

Comment: I just posted an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22509190/87015

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in Thomas' answer for [jQuery DatePicker how to disable auto day selection while browsing calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840151/jquery-datepicker-how-to-disable-auto-day-selection-while-browsing-calendar)

Adding the following to the top of my '...revised code...':

```
  if (!inst.dpuuid) {
    for (attr in window) {
      if(/^DP_jQuery_/.test(attr)) {
        inst.dpuuid = attr.replace(/^DP_jQuery_([0-9]+)/, '$1');
      }
    }
  }
  var dpuuid = inst.dpuuid;
```

eliminated the `dpuuid is not defined' error`. I had seen in FireBug that the closure scope was visible from the window object, but had no idea how to extract values from it.

Thanks Thomas!!