# jQuery UI Datepicker - How to alter Datepicker HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to make a few simple changes to the Datepicker HTML generated by the jQuery UI Datepicker e.g. adding some brief text after the calendar table.

I have been trying to do this using the beforeShow event, but while I can access the current HTML using this, manipulating it does not work:

```
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
//#this works
alert($('#ui-datepicker-div').html());
//#this does nothing
$('#ui-datepicker-div').append('message');          
}
```

I think this might be because the Datepicker HTML elements are added to the Dom later and therefore the live method is needed to update the HTML, but I do not know how to hook up the live method with this function callback. Or I could well be approaching this in the wrong way altogether.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this as I have searched and tried a lot of things but I can't seem to get this working. Thanks.

Comment: If all you're doing is adding elements to the bottom of the datepicker, why not just add those elements directly in the HTML?

Comment: Was wondering the same thing myself with a clear head this morning! :) I was hoping to avoid editing the core code if possible so that any future maintenance would be easier. I'd assumed that it would be fairly easy to manipulate the HTML from a callback and that I was just using the wrong line of code.

Comment: I want to do exactly the same thing, except I need to use wrapInner(), which again has no affect.  Funny as removeClass() and addClass() seem to work fine. I want to do this only if and when the datepicker opens...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like you need to wait till the `.ui-datepicker-calendar` table to be inserted into the `#ui-datepicker-div` to append your message. You could do a timer to check for that:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        insertMessage();
    }
});

// listen to the Prev and Next buttons
$('#ui-datepicker-div').delegate('.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next', 'click', insertMessage);

function insertMessage() {
    clearTimeout(insertMessage.timer);

    if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar').is(':visible'))
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').append('<div>foo</div>');
    else
        insertMessage.timer = setTimeout(insertMessage, 10);
}
```

<strike>See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/M9Z7T/2/.</strike>

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/M9Z7T/126/.

Comment: Brilliant William - thanks for going to the trouble of setting up an example

Comment: The message is reset when you change month.

Comment: Cool! But a mentioned before the message is reset when you change month. Is there a way to keep the message?

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar I've updated the solution to observe the Prev and Next buttons.

Comment: maybe because of my difficult datepicker, i cant post the code because to long...

Comment: It does not work with the latest versions of jquery and jquery ui. could you have a look into it? http://jsfiddle.net/M9Z7T/155/

Comment: Super helpful, after a bunch of interweb searching this is my favorite solution by far!

Answer (score 5):

```
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({ beforeShow: function () {
        setTimeout(appendsomething, 10);
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function () {
        setTimeout(appendsomething, 10);
        }
    }
    );

var appendsomething = function () {
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").append("<div class='something'>something</div>");
}
```

Comment: This appears to work when clicking the next/prev month buttons. I would suggest adding some comments around the solution to explain that this appears to solve the problem experienced by @Clyde Lobo. I've been looking around for weeks for a solution to this. Thanks!

Comment: maybe it works because of that the timer is not being cleared. In my case onChangeMonthYear doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following trick to monkey-patch the `_generateHTML` function. The following example replaces some jQuery-ui classes with jQuery-mobile classes using regular expressions. Modify according to your needs:

```
(function () {
    $.datepicker._generateHTML_old = $.datepicker._generateHTML;
    $.datepicker._generateHTML = function (inst) {
        var html = this._generateHTML_old(inst);
        html = html.replace(/<a class="(ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all)( ui-state-disabled)?"/, '<a class="$1 ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext$2"');
        html = html.replace(/<a class="(ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all)( ui-state-disabled)?"/, '<a class="$1 ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-notext$2"');
        html = html.replace(/<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-.">(.+?)<\/span>/g, '$1');
        return html;
    };
})();
```

Edit: using regex/string functions to edit HTML is actually a bad idea. Consider placing the HTML inside an element, manipulate, and grab the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as simply as this (this works with the new datepicker):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('show');
$(".ui-datepicker").append(<div>Foo</div>);

$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-next', function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker").append(<div>Foo</div>);
})

$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-prev', function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker").append(<div>Foo</div>);
})
```